# Instantiate 'this' Object

Tags: java, class, oop, serialization

I'm trying to load a serialized object within the class using a method like this one:

```
private void loadCatalog(MyClass myClassNew)
{
    this = myClassNew;
}
```

So I have this method in my ***MyClass***, and I receive as a parameter an object having the type of ***MyClass***. How can I do something like above? The code above gives me an error of which I'm not sure why. The object myClassNew is the same as the one before serializing, so I'm sure that I receive a valid object of type ***MyClass***.

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So I have the class MyClass. Within this class I have a method that is supposed to be given a single parameter, an object of type MyClass and it's supposed to attribute that object given as a parameter to the class.

Comment: Classes don't have parameters. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @shmosel  I'm in a method inside the class, I get an object of the type of the class, and I want to do something like 'this = object' where object is of type 'this'.

Comment: I can see that. But that's impossible and makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that.  You must write code that copies each instance field of MyClass from the argument to `this`.  For instance:

```
this.firstName = myClassNew.firstName;
this.lastName = myClassNew.lastName;
```

You *could* use reflection do to this, but you probably shouldn’t.  Unless MyClass is very simple, you may find that some fields require special handling.  For example, copying a List reference would be very bad, unless it’s an unmodifable List, as the two objects should share a reference to the same List object.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

"this" is not a variable that you can assign to. you can create fields in the object and do "this.field1 = myClassNew", but you cannot assign to "this".

Comment: But what about not having to do this for all the fields, but rather one attribuiting? I'm in a method inside the class, I get an object of the type of the class, and I want to do something like 'this = object' where object is of type this.